# Tweaking regular expression for Java stack trace element

Tags: java, regex, stack-trace

I'm creating a Java regular expression for matching the string form of a Java [`StackTraceElement`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api//java.base/java/lang/StackTraceElement.html). (Note that this is *not* a regular expression for the stack trace itself.) The typical forms are shown at [`StackTraceElement.toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api//java.base/java/lang/StackTraceElement.html#toString()):

> - `"com.foo.loader/foo@9.0/com.foo.Main.run(Main.java:101)"` - See the description below [in the API docs].
> - `"com.foo.loader/foo@9.0/com.foo.Main.run(Main.java)"` - The line number is unavailable.
> - `"com.foo.loader/foo@9.0/com.foo.Main.run(Unknown Source)"` - Neither the file name nor the line number is available.
> - `"com.foo.loader/foo@9.0/com.foo.Main.run(Native Method)"` - The method containing the execution point is a native method.
> - `"com.foo.loader//com.foo.bar.App.run(App.java:12)"` - The class of the execution point is defined in the unnamed module of the class loader named `com.foo.loader`.
> - `"acme@2.1/org.acme.Lib.test(Lib.java:80)"` - The class of the execution point is defined in `acme` module loaded by a built-in class loader such as the application class loader.
> - `"MyClass.mash(MyClass.java:9)"` - `MyClass` class is on the application class path.

I need to be able to access each component as a group in the resulting matcher.

Currently I have the following regular expression (not escaped for a Java string, for readability):

`(?:([^@/]+)/)?(?:(?:([^@/]+)@([\d.+-]+))?/)?([^(]+)\.([^.(]+)\(([^:)]+)(?::(\d+))??\)`

Or in Java code:

```java
public static final Pattern ELEMENT_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("(?:([^@/]+)/)?"
    + "(?:(?:([^@/]+)@([\\d.+-]+))?/)?" //optional module name/module version, followed by slash
    + "([^(]+)" //declaring class is always required
    + "\\.([^.(]+)" //method name is always required
    + "\\(([^:)]+)(?::(\\d+))??\\)"); //"file name" (always present in some form, but not necessarily the actual filename) and optional line number
```

There are two tiny drawbacks. These aren't showstoppers, but it would be nice to address them.

1. This regular expression will allow `"/com.foo.bar.App.run(App.java:12)"`, which I believe should be prohibited. Allowing "either or both of the first two components, but only a trailing slash if either are present" seems a little complicated.
2. I believe the `([^(]+)` and `\.([^.(]+)` parts will require backtracking, because the first part will consume the method name at first. I doubt this is too terribly inefficient, but I wouldn't be surprised if there is a better way.

The regular expression I have come up with is probably good enough for my purposes, but does a regex expert know how to fix those two problems I mentioned?

Comment: Like this? https://regex101.com/r/wrEMc1/1

Comment: Can the trace occur anywhere in a line? e.g. `blah blah com.foo.loader/foo@9.0/com.foo.Main.run(Main.java:101) blah blah` or are they the entire string?

Comment: @Nick this is a stack trace element, not an entire stack trace. The expression is for the entire stack trace _element_. The beginning and end anchors are not needed, as I'll be using `Pattern.matcher(…)`, which automatically matches the whole string. You reminded me of another thing, however: I do need to add `^\s` in most of the character classes, though, to prevent spaces e.g. beginning and trailing whitespace.

Comment: @GarretWilson thanks for the clarification. You could possibly add `(?!\s)` at each end of the regex to deal with the possible surrounding whitespace.

Comment: Thank you @Nick. I just added `\s` to (most of) the existing character classes—no need to add additional character classes. However this was not one of the two problems I mentioned. Do you know how to address the two shortcomings I listed?

Comment: For all the people rushing in to downvote, I've clarified the question to indicate that this regular expression has two "errors" (or at least shortcomings) and I'm asking how to mitigate them. I'm pretty sure that asking how to fix errors in a regular expression is within the scope of a permissible Stack Overflow question.

Comment: @GarretWilson Is there something wrong with the pattern I posted above?

Comment: @CAustin does your regular expression address the two problems I mentioned in the description? For example, does it match `/com.foo.bar.App.run(App.java:12)`? If it does, then it hasn't addressed the first problem I listed. How about the second problem I listed?

Comment: I would hate to have to maintain this next time the Java stack trace format changes.  From the Javadoc for `StackTraceElement`: _"`public String toString()` Returns a string representation of this stack trace element. **The format of this string depends on the implementation...** "_  This will be extremely brittle code that will break when you least expect it.  Do you have access to the `StackTraceElement` object itself, or must you depend on its string representation?  If I had to do this I would do it in 2 or 3 separate phases instead of one regex.

Comment: @GarretWilson Slightly modified: https://regex101.com/r/QQwi57/1 That said, I agree with Jim in that there are too many different things this regex is trying to do, and any solution using a single pattern will be inherently fragile and hard to maintain.

Comment: "I would hate to have to maintain this next time the Java stack trace format changes." I understand your concern here, @JimGarrison, but that is completely unrelated to the regex question I am raising. Your concern is definitely related to the problem domain, yes, but assuming I have reasons for doing what I'm doing (and I do), this question regards solely how to fix a problem in a regex.

Comment: @GarretWilson in terms of your first question, you can use a negative lookbehind before the `/` that checks it's not at the beginning of the string. In terms of the second, yes, there's some backtracking, but it's at most the length of the method name plus the dot, so I would expect it's more efficient than checking each character in the class to ensure that it's not the start of the method. I think [this](https://regex101.com/r/dbTnyX/1) is probably close to what you want.

Comment: To make this even more complicated:  a module doesn’t have to have a version.  So, `com.foo.loader/foo/com.foo.Main.run` is possible.

Comment: @GarretWilson Sometimes a "frame challenge" can be useful.

Comment: Also, [module versions need not be entirely numeric](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/module/ModuleDescriptor.Version.html) and in fact can have no digits at all (though that would be weird).

Comment: @JimGarrison you noted that these examples are not a specification, but typical strings used by JDK implementations. I had already understood that, but your emphasizing it made me realize that perhaps my regex's acceptance of `/com.foo.bar.App.run(App.java:12)` is actually a feature, not a bug. As long as the input is unambiguous as to the components, there's no reason not to accept it, as the API certainly doesn't prohibit it. Thus for that part I'll just stick with what I have in the current regex.

Answer (score 0):

Here’s what I came up with.  The most important adjustments I made are for the fact that a module version doesn’t have to be numeric.  In fact, the [specification](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/module/ModuleDescriptor.Version.html) doesn’t restrict the characters are in any way, including the use of slashes.  I tried assigning a module a version with `/` in it, and it was accepted.

```
private static final String ID =
    "\\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*";

private static final String NAME = ID + "(?:\\." + ID + ")*";

private static final String MODULE = "(" + NAME + ")(?:@(.+))?/";

/**
 * Groups:
 * <ul>
 * <li>1: classloader name
 * <li>2: module name, if loaded from custom classloader
 * <li>3: module version, if loaded from custom classloader
 * <li>4: module name, if NOT loaded from custom classloader
 * <li>5: module version, if NOT loaded from custom classloader
 * <li>6: class name
 * <li>7: method name
 * <li>8: source file
 * <li>9: line number
 * <li>10: text when line number unknown
 * </ul>
 *
 * Only class name and method name are guaranteed to be present;
 * everything else is optional.
 */
private static final Pattern STACK_TRACE_ELEMENT_PATTERN = Pattern.compile(
    "\\bat\\s+"
    + "(?:(" + NAME + ")/(?:/|" + MODULE + ")|" + MODULE + ")?"
    + "(" + NAME + ")\\.(" + ID + ")\\((?:"
        + "(" + ID + "\\.java)(?::(\\d+))?"
        + "|([^)]*)"
        + ")\\)");
```

Comment: I appreciate the work that went into this, and I am sure that I can that I can glean some useful information out of it, like improved matching of Java identifier characters and module version numbers. But really this was a regex question, not a Java question, specifically regarding whether there was an easy way to allow a slash before the class, but _only_ if a class loader and/or module was present. (I should probably have made that clearer.) Does your regex prevent `/com.foo.bar.App.run(App.java:12)` and could you explain how you do that? Is using `|` and repetition the only way?

Comment: @GarretWilson It does fail on `/com.foo.bar.App.run(App.java:12)`.  As for whether repetition is the only way… I’m not completely certain, but the more I tried to have one set of groups for the module and its version, the more the difficulty was apparent to me, so I felt like using `|` just easier overall, even at the cost of later code having to check two sets of Matcher groups.